# What's the difference between bias and biased?

Tags: meaning, differences

What's the difference between bias and biased? What is a good way to remember the difference?

Comment: You are *biased* (past tense verb used adjectivally) if your judgements exhibit *bias* (straightforward noun).

Comment: Bias is a noun or a present-tense verb. Biased is an adjective or a past-tense verb.

Answer (score 1):

Think of prejudice and prejudiced; interest and interested; shock and shocked.

The first one is the lemma or dictionary head word (the basic form of the word to which inflections can be made) and the second is the past participle acting as adjective.

Many past participles can be used as adjectives. The past participle in these examples including the one you gave describe the subject of the adjective as suffering from, being affected by, or being in a state of the word lemma (base word).